# Pandas - bucketing events close to each other

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

My question is best described by an example, say `t` is the time index, and `x` is the data, we have input

```
t = [1,2,3, 7,9,11, 17,18,20]
x = [1,2,3, 4,5,6,   7,8,9]
s = ['P', 'P', 'N',  'N', 'N', 'N', 'P', 'P', 'P']
window = 2
```

Desired output:

```
t1 = [1, 3, 7, 17]
x1 = [3, -3, -15, 24]
```

I.e. I want to cluster the x's such that if 2 consecutive samples have timestamps whose difference is <=window, and they have the same `s`value, put them together, and add up all that are in the same cluster. Moreover, those clusters that have s-value of N, make them negative.
Then, take the time stamp of the first sample in each cluster as the time for that cluster.

How do I do this in pandas?

EXPLANATION OF EXAMPLE: The clusters are (1,2), (3), (4,5,6), (7,8,9). (3) has to be in its own cluster because even though it is close to its predecessor, it has different sign. (4,5,6) are all negative (s-value is N), so the assigned value for that cluster is -(4+5+6) = -15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a start.  Given a dataframe of your values, add three new columns with the data shifted once backwards.  Also add a signed version of x.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t':t, 'x':x, 's':s})
df[['s_1', 't_1', 'x_1']] = df.shift(-1)
df['x_signed'] = np.where(df['s'] == 'N', -1 * df['x'], df['x'])
```

Add a boolean column that represents the start of a new cluster, based on your two possible conditions.

```
df['cluster'] = (df['s'] != df['s_1']) | (df['t_1'] - df['t'] > window)
```

Convert this into group numbers, by shifting backwards once, filling the first value (group 0), converting to integers, and then taking a cumulative sum.

```
df['cluster'] = df['cluster'].shift(1).fillna(False).astype(int).cumsum()
```

Then from there, it's pretty easy to groupby and get your output.

```
In [72]: df.groupby('cluster').agg({'t':'first', 'x_signed':'sum'})
Out[72]: 
          t  x_signed
cluster              
0         1         3
1         3        -3
2         7       -15
3        17        24
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it at some point today, and accept the answer if it really works.