# reduce datetime list by timedelta

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

in python, how I can reduce a datetime list by a timedelta neighborhood?

If I have

```
    dates = [
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 2),
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 3),
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 7),
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 8)
    ]
```

and a timedelta

```
delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=2)
```

How I can get this ?

```
    expected = [
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 2, 30),
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 7, 30)
    ]
```

## EDIT

A example with numbers, if I have this number list

```
numbers = [1,2,6,7]
delta = 1
```

I try to group the nearly values and get a characteristic value (a central value) of the group. The delta is the max distance between the values.

for the numbers, the characteristic value is

```
[1.5, 6.5]
```

Because the values are grouped in [1,2] and [6,7] and calculated the average value.

Comment: Just to be clear, is your goal to run through the initial list and eliminate any entries within the time delta of the current value?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by timedelta neborhood ?
In the expected you add 30 seconds to the first and third value.

Comment: @tgdn a neighborhood is a group of nearly values

Comment: Sounds like you want some kind of clustering algorithm. Maybe Pandas has something like that available out of the box. A bit like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25516477/pandas-bucketing-events-close-to-each-other

Comment: What should be the output of ```[1,2,3,4]``` with ```delta = 1```?

Comment: What do you expect the results to be for grouping the following examples: numbers = [1,2,3,6,7], delta = 1? or numbers = [1,2,3,4,6,7], delta = 1? I am guessing [1.5, 3, 6.5], and [1.5, 3.5, 6.5] respectively.

Comment: @JuanPablo, do you mean ```[1.5, 3.5]```? Otherwise your response makes no sense

Comment: @wnnmaw, sorry, I don't read fine. I never have a case like [1,2,3,4] with delta = 1. Normally first I see the data before to take a delta.

Comment: are the datetimes always sorted?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham yes, first I sorted the datetimes

Comment: Is something like this what you want? http://pastebin.com/QhknmjMD

Comment: @PadraicCunningham http://ideone.com/ecmg6L

Comment: @JuanPablo I was ignoring the year, http://pastebin.com/i3KBeEkS

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, yes no problem ;) , you can submit your comment as a answer ?

Comment: @JuanPablo, that will only work when the year is 1970, I presume you can have any year? I will add an answer that should work for any year

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt

dates = [
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 2),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 3),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 12),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 7),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 8),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 9),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 13)
]

def group_dates(dates, delta):
    it = iter(dates)
    prev = next(it)
    grouped, total =  [[prev]], delta.total_seconds()
    for dte in it:
        if (dte - prev).total_seconds() <= total:
            grouped[-1].append(dte)
        else:
            grouped.append([dte])
        prev = dte
    return grouped
def td(l):
    seconds = sum((d - dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds() for d in l) / len(l)
    return dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds)


from pprint import pprint as pp
pp([td(sub) for sub in group_dates(dates,dt.timedelta(minutes=2))])
```

To avoid unnecessary function calls, check the len:

```
pp([td(sub) if len(sub) > 1 else sub[0] for sub in [datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 2, 30),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 12),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 8),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 13)]group_dates(dates,dt.timedelta(minutes=2))])
```

Or yield the values as you go:

```
def group_dates(dates, delta):
    it = iter(dates)
    prev = next(it)
    grouped, total = (prev,),delta.total_seconds()
    for dte in it:
        if (dte - prev).total_seconds() <= total:
            grouped = grouped + (dte,)
        else:
            yield td(grouped)
            grouped = (dte,)
        prev = dte
    yield td(grouped)

pp(list(group_dates(dates,  delta=dt.timedelta(minutes=2))))
[datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 2, 30),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 12),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 8),
 datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 13)]
```

Some timings:

```
In [28]: dates = [                                                         
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 2),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 3),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 4),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 7),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 8),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 9),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 15),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 22),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 24),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 27)
]

In [41]: for i in range(10000):    
          dates.append(dates[-1]+dt.timedelta(minutes=choice([1,2,3,4])))
   ....:     
In [42]: timeit [td(sub) if len(sub) > 1 else sub[0] for sub in group_dates(dates,dt.timedelta(minutes=2))]
100 loops, best of 3: 15.8 ms per loop

In [43]: timeit reduce_datetime_list_by_delta(dates, delta)                         
100 loops, best of 3: 16.9 ms per loop

In [44]: timeit timestamps = map(avgtm, groupby(dates, key=grouper(delta)))
10 loops, best of 3: 18.8 ms per loop

In [45]: timeit (list(group_dates_iter(dates,  delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=2))))
10 loops, best of 3: 18.4 ms per loop
```

Comment: yes ... but what happend with the `dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 12)` value ? this value should be in a separate group

Comment: Ah ok, I meant to ask you what should happen when there is only a single date. You just keep the date?

Comment: @JuanPablo, edited, I should have added prev at the beginning and based the logic on that. You can avoid storing all the datetimes by doing the calculation in the loop, storing temp consecutive elements

Answer (score 2):

The problem description already gives it away: you want to use the `groupby()` function from `itertools`

All that is needed is a slightly smarter `key` function, one that remembers the last state and keeps on giving the same `key` value as long as successive time stamps are closer closer than `delta`.

After grouping, transform the found groups to average times, taking care of single time stamps (example included).

```
import datetime as dt
from itertools import groupby

dates = [
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 2),
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 3),
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 7),
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 8),
        dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 13)
    ]
delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=2)

class grouper:
    def __init__(self, delta):
        self.delta= delta
        self.last = None

    def __call__(self, tm):
        # we keep on returning the same key as long as successive time
        # stamps are within the last time stamp + delta
        self.last = tm if (self.last is None) or (tm - self.last)>self.delta \
                       else self.last
        return self.last

# transform the result of groupby into average times
def avgtm(item):
    (key, tms) = item
    tms = list(tms) # transform generator into list so we can index it
    return tms[0] + (tms[-1]-tms[0])/2 if len(tms)>1 else tms[0]

timestamps = map(avgtm, groupby(dates, key=grouper(delta)))
print "Time stamps: ",timestamps
```

Yields output:

```
Time stamps:  [datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 2, 30), 
               datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 7, 30),
               datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 13)]
```

Comment: Using `itertools.groupby` with a suitable comparator is the first thing which came to my mind, too. Instead of `self.last is None` you could just say `not self.last` though, and 'avgtm' coupld be simplifed a bit if you used a generator expression as in `timestamps = (avgtm(list(tms)) for (_, tms) in groupby(dates, key=grouper(delta)))` instead of `map.`

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt

def datetime_to_epoch(dtime):
    return (dtime - dt.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()

def datetime_sublists(datetime_list, time_delta = dt.timedelta(days=1)):
    sublists = []

    temp = [datetime_list[0]]
    for i in range(len(datetime_list)-1):
        prev_date = datetime_list[i]
        current_date = datetime_list[i+1]

        if current_date - prev_date <= time_delta:
            temp.append(current_date)
        else:
            sublists.append(temp)
            temp = [current_date]
    sublists.append(temp)

    return sublists

def reduce_datetime_list_by_delta(date_list, delta):
    sublist = datetime_sublists(date_list, delta)

    reduced = []
    for dates in sublist:
        epochs = [ datetime_to_epoch(date) for date in dates]
        epoch_average = sum(epochs)/len(epochs)
        reduced.append(dt.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_average))

    return reduced


dates = [
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 2),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 3),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 7),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 8),
    dt.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 12)
]

delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=2)

print reduce_datetime_list_by_delta(dates, delta)
```